# Rails + Will paginate paginating a list presenter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

Today i am trying to present the items from a list that were paginated:

```
users = User.order('name').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => 1).map{|u| UserPresenter.new(e)}
```

The problem is that users is no longer (after mapping to my presenter) an array wrapped with will_paginate magic, so it does not contains such things like total_entries, per_page or page, then the will_paginate helper is not working in my view :S .

How should i proceed to paginate a list of post-processed objects?

I've tried doing the other way around but then if i have a huge amount of records in my table it will be really painful because it will paginate from a big result set that is already retrieved:

```
users = User.order('name').map{|u| UserPresenter.new(u)}.paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => 1)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you still use `users` for `will_paginate` and add another instance variables for presenters.

```
@users = User.order('name').paginate(:per_page => 10, :page => 1)
@presenters = @users.map { |u| UserPresenter.new(u) }
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I would try to create a UserCollectionPresenter and a UserPresenter this way

```
class UserCollectionPresenter
  include Enumerable

  delegate :paginate, to: :collection

  attr_reader :collection

  def initialize(collection)
    @collection = collection
    @_presentable_collection = collection.map { |user| UserPresenter.new(user) }
  end

  def each(&block)
    @_presentable_collection.each(&block)
  end

  def total_count
    @collection.limit(nil).offset(nil).count
  end
end
```

And

```
class UserPresenter
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  private

  attr_reader :user
end
```

In the controller u should send the paginated AR collection and later u can use paginate. Not sure which methods u need from will_paginate but i would think of either delegating, "overriding" them or include them from will_paginate directly.